# delete a node at nth position IN C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am having problems deleting from an arbitrary position given in a linked list. I succeeded for the first position and last position of my list but got a runtime error when going for the nth position.

```
struct node
{
    int number;
    node *next;
};

struct Box
{
    void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last,int number);
    void insert(node *&head, node *&last,int number);
    void remove(node *&head, node *&last);
    void showList(node *current);
};

bool isEmpty(node *head) {
    return head == NULL;
}

char menu() {
    char choice;
    cout<<"Menu"<<"1. Add an item.\n"<<"2. Remove an item.\n"<<"3. Show the list.\n"<<"Exit\n";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last,int number) {
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->number = number;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    last = temp;
}

void insert(node *&head, node *&last,int number) {
    if(isEmpty(head))
      insertAsFirstElement(head, last, number);
    else {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->number = number;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

void remove(node *&head, node *&last,int number) {
    cin>>number;
    node *temp = new node;
    if(isEmpty(head))
        cout<< "this list is already empty.\n";
    else if (head == last) {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; 1< number-2; i++)
            /*node *temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;*/
            node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        temp= temp->next;
        node* temp2 = temp->next;
        temp->next = temp2->next;
        delete temp2;
    }
}

void showList(node *current) {
    if(isEmpty(current))
        cout << "The list is empty\n";
    else {
        cout << "The list contains:\n";
        while(current != NULL) {
            cout << current->number << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    node *head = NULL;
    node *last = NULL;
    char choice;
    int number;
    do{
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice) {
        case'1':
            cout << "please enter a number: ";
            cin >> number;
            insert (head,last,number);
            break;
        case'2':
            remove(head,last,number);
            break;
        case '3':
            showList(head);
            break;
        default:
            cout<< "System exit\n";
        }
    }while (choice !='4');
}
```

Comment: **What** runtime error?  Which line did it correspond to?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: when i try deleting from position in list it gives error

Comment: @KingJosh ***WHAT*** error specifically?

Comment: it does not explicitly tell the kind of error. its a run time error when i try deleting from a position the program stops and says "a problem has occured windows.........." then program ends

Comment: but adding to the list works just fine

Comment: What happened when you stepped through with your debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition in the removal function is wrong, it's not checking anything affected by the loop, so it would just run forever (or more likely, until it breaks something).

In addition, your `remove` is not matching its signature. Since you didn't really explain what you want it to do, it's hard to say how to fix it - is `number` the value you want to remove (what if there are multiple ones?) is it the index to remove? is it a number of elements to remove?

I'll assume it's the second, as it seems like what you were trying to do. In any cases you need to *search* for that item before deleting it, so instead of -

```
for(int i = 0; 1< number-2; i++)
```

try

```
for(int i = 0; i < number-1; i++)
```

The 1 was probably a typo, and it's enough to stop one element ahead (the index meaning is up to you, but if the head is 0, then deleting index 2 should run the loop once)

Then, you need to put some brackets around your loop, since right now you're only looping over the first line of code. Move the assignment of `temp = head` ahead of the loop, you only need to do it once, and loop over

```
temp= temp->next;
```

(if that's your only line you don't need brackets, but it's a good habit anyway).
That should bring you to the element ahead of your index. If that's the head, you need some special treatment, but otherwise don't change `head`, or you'll lose elements you want to keep.

The actual removal looks like it might work, but everytime you dereference `next`, you need to make sure it's not NULL.

Comment: Thanks A lot. I'll try implementing it to see if it works.

Comment: I just implemented it, it works but only deletes the middle element of my list although i input the position i want deleted. pls how do i make it the position i want deleted how i make it delete from the position i want if i am using numbers to determine the position